# Listener on MenuBar in Vaadin

Tags: listener, vaadin, mvp, menubar, clicklistener

I want to add a ClickListener to an Item of a MenuBar in Vaadin.

I know about the normal situation, which i got working:

```
MenuBar menubar = new MenuBar();
menubar.addItem("Item", new MenuBar.Command() {

                    @Override
                    public void menuSelected(MenuItem selectedItem) {
                        //Do sth. when item is clicked
                    }
                });
```

In my application, I'm working with MVP, so the code which should run, is in an other class than the code which is defining the menubar.

Is there a way to add a listener to a specific item in the menubar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add an item to your `MenuBar` the function `addItem(String,Command)` actually returns a `MenuItem` which can be used later. You can do this :

```
MenuItem select = menuBar.addItem("Select", null);
```

And in another context you can add a listener on that `MenuItem` like this:

```
select.setCommand(new Command() {

  @Override
  public void menuSelected(MenuItem selectedItem) {
    System.out.println("You clicked on "+selectedItem.getText());
  }
});
```